# How to create a plugin that includes all the other plugins?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

Is there a way to create a plugin which include others plugins? Obviously I will take care of updating all the plugins included in mine. I haven't found any info about it.

Basically I want to package various basic plugins I always use for my less tech-savvy clients into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do such a thing, either for security, copyright, and other reasons. You can use a plugin management tool. There is a famous one, called [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/).

You can include plugins for your works by many ways, such as from the repository, external URL, or even a pre-packaged zip file in your theme ( Not recommended ).